# Download a file from protected page

Tags: javascript

I use the syntax below to download the file described in it, but it was opening in another page instead of downloading it.
The syntax is as follow;

```js
function passwd() {
  var password = prompt('Enter the pin to download the file: ');

  if (password.toLowerCase() == "1472") {
    window.open("folder/file")

  } else {
    alert("incorrect password!! please try again");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="download" onClick="passwd()" />
```

Comment: You understand that it's now actually protected because anyone can see the right password, right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download File Using Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery) specifically - https://stackoverflow.com/a/9834261/863110

Comment: ***Never*** validate passwords on the client side. Always validate it on the server.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of issues in your code as mentioned in the comments before. However, as an answer to your question, if you want to open the window in the same tab, you need to send "_self" parameter. Like this:

```
 window.open("folder/file", "_self")
```